# Mongo Nested Arrays and (Partial) Unique Indexes

Tags: arrays, mongodb, unique-constraint

I'm using MongoDB v3.2. I have objects in a collection that have the following form:

```js
{
  ...
  root_array: [
    {
      ...
      child_array: [
         { 
           id: 'some-uuid'
         }
      ]
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
      child_array: [
         { 
           id: 'some-other-uuid'
         }
      ]
      ...
    }
    {
      ...
      child_array: [
        // possibly empty
      ]
      ...
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

I would like to have a unique index on this collection that enforces the constraint that, across the entire collection, no child_array element objects have the same value for the id field. The way I would have *wanted* to state that simply is:

```js
    collection.createIndex({ 
      'root_array.child_array.id': 1 
    }, {
      unique: true
    });
```

... which actually does the job, except for the fact that not all child_arrays are non-empty. So two degenerate objects (with empty one-element root_arrays, containing a zero-element child_array) cause a constraint violation. This would usually lead me to try and specify a partialFilterExpression to relax the constraint. However, I don't see a way to do that in this case. The expression that I would want to state would look something like this:

```js
    collection.createIndex({ 
      'root_array.child_array.id': 1 
    }, {
      unique: true,
      partialFilterExpression: {
        'root_array.child_array': {$gt: ''} 
      }
    });
```

... but this seems wrong too because the following two objects would likewise cause a constraint violation:

```js
   { root_array: [ { child_array: [ { id: 1 } ] }, { child_array: [] } ] }
   { root_array: [ { child_array: [ { id: 2 } ] }, { child_array: [] } ] }
```

... because both elements satisfy the partialFilterExpression and both documents have a child_array with no elements (and hence an undefined id for one of their children).

Is it intractable to specify this as a database constraint, and must it be handled as an application-level concern? Or is there some way to get at what I'm saying here in the database, without fundamentally changing the structure of the documents in question?

Comment: It looks like there is no way to specify the condition that the unique constraint applies to only for `child_array` size greater than zero (non-empty array). The operators that can be used are [these](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/index.html#create-a-partial-index) and the usage of the `expr` operator is not allowed. **Question**: At the application level, why do you need an empty `child_array`?

Comment: ah, that is a good question... so basically just don't have a child_array attribute at all if it would merely contain an empty array. That is an interesting suggestion... just preclude that from happening on the documents submitted to Mongo and if the front-end really needs that then patch it outbound from the server.